# Django Rest Framework+React app - only showing a blank page, browser can't find react frontend's static files

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

Have finished and built a todo app using the DRF and React. However when I run the app on the local server all I can see is a blank page and these errors on the console:

127.0.0.1/:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/main.f160e951.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

127.0.0.1/:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/2.9db42ba3.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

127.0.0.1/:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/main.77fbf7b1.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Not sure why the front end static files can't be found, can anyone help?

[App structure/tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFAbb.png)

settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'dx%a3t6x5tu)k9h16arn@r+^#qticx%+jm9@_ug%!u@kqhc3bp'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'rest_framework',

    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'todo_drf.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend_react/build'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'todo_drf.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend_react/build/static'),
]



CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [

    "http://localhost:3000",
]

# CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS - alternative but didn't work
r code here
```

Project's url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/',include('api.urls')),
path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
```

]

The error in the console says the source is this build/index.html file, here are its contents:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@700&family=Marck+Script&family=Xanh+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>React App</title><link href="/static/css/main.f160e951.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script>!function(e){function r(r){for(var n,a,i=r[0],c=r[1],l=r[2],s=0,p=[];s<i.length;s++)a=i[s],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,a)&&o[a]&&p.push(o[a][0]),o[a]=0;for(n in c)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(c,n)&&(e[n]=c[n]);for(f&&f(r);p.length;)p.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,l||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,i=1;i<t.length;i++){var c=t[i];0!==o[c]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=a(a.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function a(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,a),t.l=!0,t.exports}a.e=function(e){var r=[],t=o[e];if(0!==t)if(t)r.push(t[2]);else{var n=new Promise((function(r,n){t=o[e]=[r,n]}));r.push(t[2]=n);var u,i=document.createElement("script");i.charset="utf-8",i.timeout=120,a.nc&&i.setAttribute("nonce",a.nc),i.src=function(e){return a.p+"static/js/"+({}[e]||e)+"."+{3:"87951512"}[e]+".chunk.js"}(e);var c=new Error;u=function(r){i.onerror=i.onload=null,clearTimeout(l);var t=o[e];if(0!==t){if(t){var n=r&&("load"===r.type?"missing":r.type),u=r&&r.target&&r.target.src;c.message="Loading chunk "+e+" failed.\n("+n+": "+u+")",c.name="ChunkLoadError",c.type=n,c.request=u,t[1](c)}o[e]=void 0}};var l=setTimeout((function(){u({type:"timeout",target:i})}),12e4);i.onerror=i.onload=u,document.head.appendChild(i)}return Promise.all(r)},a.m=e,a.c=n,a.d=function(e,r,t){a.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},a.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},a.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=a(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(a.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)a.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},a.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return a.d(r,"a",r),r},a.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},a.p="/",a.oe=function(e){throw console.error(e),e};var i=this.webpackJsonpfrontend_react=this.webpackJsonpfrontend_react||[],c=i.push.bind(i);i.push=r,i=i.slice();for(var l=0;l<i.length;l++)r(i[l]);var f=c;t()}([])
</script><script src="/static/js/2.9db42ba3.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.77fbf7b1.chunk.js"></script></body></html>
```

The src/index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.js';
import './App.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. 
reportWebVitals();
```

The public/index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />


    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@700&family=Marck+Script&family=Xanh+Mono&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">

    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials"/>

      <!-- Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Would be grateful for any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Not sure if relevant but just wanted to add that files called '3.87951... .chunk.js' and 'runtime-main.2c941... .js' are in the same directory as the files in the error messages, but I don't get any mention of errors for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this helps anyone, I'd typed STATICFILES_DIR instead of STATICFILES_DIRS, it's working now.